# Does squidman proxy server support https?

Tags: macos, proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up a proxy server on my local mac.

http - seems to work.

But Safari is not connecting via https.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. You need to specify a separate https port and a ssl certificate, as documented in the squid config:

> The socket address where Squid will listen for client requests made
>     over TLS or SSL connections. Commonly referred to as HTTPS.
>
> This is most useful for situations where you are running squid in
>     accelerator mode and you want to do the TLS work at the accelerator
>     level.
>
> You may specify multiple socket addresses on multiple lines,    each
>   with their own certificate and/or options.
>
> The tls-cert= option is mandatory on HTTPS ports.
>
> See http_port for a list of modes and options.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/https_port/

By design, it is quite hard to intercept https traffic:

> When a browser creates a direct secure connection with an origin
>   server, there are no HTTP CONNECT requests. The first HTTP request
>   sent on such a connection is already encrypted. In most cases, Squid
>   is out of the loop: Squid knows nothing about that connection and
>   cannot block or proxy that traffic.

You also need to load the proxy settings for the browser as a PAC file, otherwise the browsers won't connect or throw a certificate warning:

> Chrome The Chrome browser is able to connect to proxies over SSL
>   connections if configured to use one in a PAC file or command line
>   switch. GUI configuration appears not to be possible (yet).
>
> More details at
>   http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy
>
> Firefox The Firefox 33.0 browser is able to connect to proxies over
>   TLS connections if configured to use one in a PAC file. GUI
>   configuration appears not to be possible (yet), though there is a
>   config hack for embedding PAC logic.
>
> There is still an important bug open:
>
> Using a client certificate authentication to a proxy:
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209312

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS